# words/phrases for overtaking cars in a race

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, american-english, british-english, phrasal-verbs

I want some words or phrases that describe overtaking car or cars, like in a race. I've heard "make up places" in Top Gear and have been wondering about other ways to say it.

Comment: 'out in front' 'in first place' 'leading the pack'

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> [Gain the lead](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gain%20the%20lead): to take the winning position in a race or competition Her car has *gained the lead*. Our team *gained the lead* in the eighth inning.
>
> —often used figuratively: Their company has *gained the lead* in developing this new technology.

*Merriam Webster*

Answer (score 0):

Move up

He'll move up to second place if he can pass Jimmy Jones.

Gain

He's gained four places in the last ten laps.

Answer (score -1):

- **leave behind**
- **pull ahead of**
- **go by**
- **overtake**

All of these are some synonyms for [pass](https://www.freethesaurus.com/pass.)